# Setting up to invoke form helpers from Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I'd like to experiment with using form helpers inside the Rails console, but my simple minded approach of doing `extend ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper` didn't work. For example, subsequently calling `form_for` resulted in the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'dom_class' for main:Object`. Using `include` produces the same results.

Is there an "easy" way to enable me to call form helpers from the console? I'd prefer to do this without any dependency on controller or view files, if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Peter, I'm happy to solve your problem.

For simple view helpers, it's very easy

```
> app.helper.link_to 'root', app.root_path
# <a href = ....> # as expected
```

However your specific case is not that easy as form_for needs `view_context` and then a controller instance to work.

```
# Get a controller instance at first. Must do it.
# Without this step `app.controller` is nil
> app.get app.root_path

# Use an instance variable but not variable!
> @user = User.last

# Get the view
# Note you need to take the trouble to define url manually
# because console can only reach path through app instance
> app.controller.view_context.form_for(@user, url: app.user_path(@user)){|f| f.input :name}
# Job done
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use include, not extend:

```
irb(main):007:0> include ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper
=> Object
irb(main):008:0> form_for
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Comment: See updated question. The issue is not the ability to invoke the method. The issue is satisfying the dependencies of the method(s).

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that part. Can you try something like this? http://6brand.com/undefined-method-dom_class.html