# How do I print a form on the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to debug a date field. I'm getting the following error. How do I print a form and form helpers from the console?

```
irb(main):014:0> p
=> #<Principal id: 1, company_id: 31, name: "Jim", title: "CMO", address: "Seattle, WA", ssn: "1112223333", dob: "1970-01-01", created_at: "2017-09-21 20:07:31", updated_at: "2017-09-21 20:07:31">
irb(main):015:0> helper.form_for p do |pf|
irb(main):016:1* end
NoMethodError: undefined method `polymorphic_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000009c3d878>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails 5 you can use [`ActionController::Renderer`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionController/Renderer.html) like so:

```
form = ApplicationController.render inline:<<-FORM
  <%= form_for MyResource.new do |form| %>
  <% end %>
FORM

puts form
# => <form class="new_my_resource" id="new_my_resource" action="/my_resources" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
#      <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
#      <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="..." />
#    </form>
```

Comment: For Rails 4 and below where `ActionController::Renderer` isn't available, this answer documents how to set the app controller and invoke the form helper: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20937168/7014122